# Read a file in python starting with a particular string

Tags: python, file, pandas, dataframe, wildcard

I have a file in the following path:

```
/home/[user]/foo_01-01-2016.txt
```

I need to read it using the wild card (*) character:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/home/[user]/foo_*.txt")
```

But its giving a file not found error.

Comment: I don't think in that case [path expansion](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Path_name_expansion) is supported. I would use this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: The `*` is used by a shell.  If you use it from any other language you have to translate it yourself, one way is to use `glob` from the Python standard library (filename expansion is known as *globbing*).https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html), but output is list, so select first item by `[0]`:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path =r'/home/[user]'
filename = glob.glob(path + "/foo_*.txt")
print (filename[0])

df = pd.read_csv(filename[0])
print (df)
```

Comment: What is that 'r' before the file path?

Comment: It means raw string, not regex. It prevents backslash escape translation. `r'\x41'` is 4 bytes. Without `r` it is one byte.